# Consume REST service that returns a single value

Tags: web-services, rest, iframe, xmlhttprequest, restful-url

I am used to consuming Web services via a XMLHttpRequest, to retrieve xml or JSON.

Recently, I have been working with SharePoint REST services, which can return a single value (for example 5532, or "Jeff"). I am wondering if there is a more efficient way than XMLHttpRequest to retrieve this single value. For example, would it work if I loaded the REST url via an iframe, then retrieved the iframe content? Or is there any other well established method?

[Edit] By single value, I really mean that the service just returns these characters. This is not even presented in a JSON or xml response.

Comment: If you've done everything you can think of and XHR is too heavyweight, maybe you need to rethink the problem.

Comment: Well, you're right, and I have alternate options. But I am trying to push the REST one as far as I can.

Comment: The only way to retrieve data over HTTP is to retrieve data over HTTP. Whether you do it though XHR or an iframe... it doesn't matter. Consider batching up a bunch of requests all at once and returning them all in one go.

Comment: I understand. I was just trying to see if some ways are more efficient, for example by passing a smaller message. I am not even sure if the iframe idea would work at all.

Comment: An iframe still causes an HTTP request like XHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any inefficiency in `XMLHttpRequest` is largely due to the overhead of HTTP, which the iframe approach is going to incur, as well.  Furthermore, if the Sharepoint service expects to speak HTTP, you're going to need to speak HTTP.  However, an API does not have to run over HTTP to be RESTful, per Roy Fielding, so if the service provided an API over a raw socket -- or if you simply wanted to craft your own slimmer HTTP request -- you could use a Flash socket via a library like: http://code.google.com/p/javascript-as3-socket/.  You could cut the request message size down to under 100 bytes, and could pull out the response data trivially.

Comment: Makes sense. iframe is the only thing I could think of, that's why I posted my question. I don't really have control on the tools, it's just JavaScript consuming existing services.

Comment: Yeah, I get it.  If you want to leverage HTTP, then honestly XMLHttpRequest is the way to go, unless you have some sort of same-origin issues to get around -- it's popular, well-supported, well-understood, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) library is a well established framework which you can use. It´s also an article which answer your concrete question at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637818/how-do-i-get-a-single-json-value-using-webmatrix-razor).

Comment: Your examples are XMLHttpRequest. I am retrieving a single value, and looking for a lighter method.